SQL format mask to clean up freeform data before and after a special character like '-'
I'm using SQL Server 2016 and trying to implement a format mask to clean up some freeform text held in the database.
I'm wanted to extract all the numbers directly before and after the '-' into a new column, not including any number divided by a space.
Here are some of the variations of data I have:
'Widget 1234-12345 Blah Blah',
'12345-12345_A',
'123456-123456 and 6789-12345'
'12 1234567-1234567'

the output should look like this:
1234-12345
12345-12345
123456-123456
1234567-1234567


T-SQL really isn't the "best" language for this; it lacks support for things like Regex and has only rudimentary pattern matching. You would be better off doing this outside of SQL Server.

"I want" and "should be" are no questions. What exactly is unclear to you?

SQL, the language, isn't good at string manipulation, and T-SQL is worst than most. It would be a lot easier to do this in on the client, preferably before loading the data. What you want requires regular expressions, eg \d+-\d+. That's not available in any SQL Server version. It's a private preview feature in Azure SQL which means it won't come before SQL Server 2025 (at least)

SQL Server 2016 and 2017 added the ability to execute R and Python scripts using sp_execute_external_script on query results. In Python, what you ask could be as simple as my_input_data["cleaned"]=my_input_data["source"].str.extract(r'\d+-\d+') followed by OutputDataSet=my_input_data to get the results out. Not terribly fast, but at least the code executes on the server machine. Or you could write the same in a standalone Python script

If you use SSIS, you could create a script transformation that uses .NET's Regex with the same pattern

Very simple in something like PowerShell as well. Using a literal assigned to a variable for demonstration: $String = '123456-123456 and 6789-12345'; $String -match '(\d+-\d+)' | Out-Null; $Matches[0] returns 123456-123456

Here's something to get you started (just because you provided some samples):
select *
from (
    VALUES  (N'Widget 1234-12345 Blah Blah')
    ,   (N'12345-12345_A')
    ,   (N'123456-123456 and 6789-12345')
    ,   (N'12 1234567-1234567')
) t (col)
cross apply STRING_SPLIT(TRANSLATE(col, '_:|,.', '     '), ' ') x
where x.value like '%[0-9]-[0-9]%'
and x.value not like '%[^-0-9]%'
--and x.value not like '%-%-%' -- Maybe not needed

Main idea is that you want to split string by space, and then retrieve the pattern you're looking for. For that, i use TRANSLATE function to turn all separators into spaces which simplifies latter work.
Then to match the desired pattern i use:
LIKE %[0-9]-[0-9]%
NOT LIKE %[^-0-9]%

patterns which make sure non-numbers and dashes aren't allowed, as well as that the needed pattern is achieved. Sure, you might get some other bad patterns like: -0- but these can be easily filtered by adding %-%-% etc.
This code needs sql server 2017 for TRANSLATE function, if you're sitting on earlier, you can use nested REPLACEs

"This code needs sql server 2022 for TRANSLATE function" FYI, TRANSLATE was added in SQL Server 2017, not 2022. Still, however, a later version than the OP is using.

Woops, edited, thanks! I have 2016 and 2022 running, so assumed it was added later

Yeah, I get confused from time to time as well. We have 2016, 2019, and 2022 in the "estate"; the 2016 instance is painful to work on at times due to missing features (and more so when I need code transferable on all 3 environments and therefore can't use them on 2022 either... :( )

In their first sentence, OP write they use 2016.
